# "npm ci" command causing longer build time on gitlab than the "npm i"

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, npm-install

Due to certain suggestions received from different articles, we have decided to use the "npm ci" to install the node dependencies from package-lock.json file to avoid breaking changes instead of using the "npm install" script.

But after making this change in .gitlab-ci.yml file, the builds are taking much more time to get install the dependencies. It has been increased from 7 minutes to around 23 minutes.

As per the attached screenshot, it looks like taking more time in removing the existing node_modules folder before installation -

[image]

Below are some details from the script file -

```
image: docker:latest

# When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
# improved performance.
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - test and build
#  - documentation-server
  - deploy

variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
#  ELECTRON_SKIP_BINARY_DOWNLOAD: 1

build:library:
  image: trion/ng-cli-karma
  stage: test and build
  only:
    - master
    - /^.*/@library_name
  script:
    - echo _auth=${NPM_TOKEN} >> .npmrc
    - mkdir -p dist/core
    - cd dist/core
    - npm init -y
    - cd ../..
    - ls -al /hugo
    - npm ci
```

Any help or suggestions would be really helpful to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you include 'package-lock.json' in your repo files?

Comment: Yes, we do. Every time if there is any update in package-lock.json file we also commit it along with other code changes.

Comment: You can increase the speed by [Caching dependencies in Gitlab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-nodejs-dependencies)